# Sending a message from one controller to another

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

When I register a user, it redirects to the Manage controller (where the user profile is).

`return RedirectToAction("Index", "Manage", new { id = user.Id });`

and in the Manage Controller

```
[Route("")]
        [Route("{id}")]
        public ActionResult Index(string id)
        {

            if (id == null)
            {
                id = User.Identity.GetUserId();
            }


            var user = UserManager.FindById(id);

            return View(user);
        }
```

I need to send a string message of "newUser", so I can display a modal message the first time the user makes the account and is redirected  to their profile.

My question is how exactly? I tried to send a string parameter like this:

`return RedirectToAction("Index", "Manage", new { id = user.Id, msg = "newUser" });`

and change the Index constructor to `Index(string id, string msg)` but for some reason both the id and msg get the value of the user id.

Anyone know a solution to this?

Manage / Index

```
public ActionResult Index(string id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                id = User.Identity.GetUserId();
            }


            var user = UserManager.FindById(id);

            return View(user);
        }
```

Comment: I removed it and same thing happened. The URL however ends in "&msg=newUser" when being redirected for some reason??

Comment: again .... the problem the message ends up taking the value of id, but how??? this seems so random

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of TempData for passing data from one controller to anhother.

Example :

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
  var model = new Review()
        {
            Body = "Start",
            Rating=5
        };
    TempData["ModelName"] = model;
    return RedirectToAction("About");
}


public ActionResult About() 
{     
    var model= TempData["ModelName"];     
    return View(model); 
}
```

Refer this link for more info : https://www.codeproject.com/articles/476967/what-is-viewdata-viewbag-and-tempdata-mvc-option

Comment: No matter what and how I tried this TempData seems to not do anything...

Comment: Hello there is problem in your metod  Manage-> Index

Comment: you need to change your action method with 2 paramters like :

Put this method as a solution with . Storing mesage in ViewBag and then display that ViewBag.Message  in your View.


ManageController :

    public ActionResult Index(string id,string msg)
            {

            if (id == null)
            {
                id = User.Identity.GetUserId();
            }

            var user = UserManager.FindById(id);
            ViewBag.Message = msg;

            return View(user);
        }

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148862/discussion-between-dilip-and-crystyxn).

Answer (score 0):

You code syntax is almost correct except you are missing **"** in **msg = "newUser**

Comment: sorry, when I typed this I forgot, but not in the code

Comment: Then the problem is with routing. You have to add two parameters in the ActionResult.

Comment: I removed the routes but its the same result

Comment: Did you add two parameters in the method ?

Comment: Yes, sent 2 parameters from AccountController and changed the Index method to `public ActionResult Index(string id, string msg)` inside the ManageController. msg ends up having the same value as id.

Comment: is id and msg both are going in string format as written in ActionResult ?

Comment: Yes, they are both strings

Comment: If you are using this code, i doubt id is goingin integer format.
new { id = user.Id, msg = "newUser" });

Comment: they are both strings, not integers

Answer (score 0):

You could have use TempData for sending data from controller to controller.

For more reference :

http://www.tutorialsteacher.com/mvc/tempdata-in-asp.net-mvc

Comment: This doesn't seem to do anything, even though I did it exactly like in the example. Maybe its because its different controllers, not methods inside the same controller?